# Showing images in tile view and rearrange them

Tags: objective-c, ios4, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer

I want to make a small app such that  ->

1. It fetches all images from Photo Library and display in view , similar to as we see apps arranged   on a iPad/iPhone.
2. These images can be dragged and rearranged.

How should I proceed , and  Which libraries may be helpful for the same ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at Alan Quatermains [AQGridview](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/aqtoolkit). It mimics the UITableView, but arranges the cells in a grid defined by cell size. If you plan to locate the tiles over multiple pages, I would recommend using a scrollview with several instances of the AQGridView to increase performance and memory usage. My experience is that AQGridview doesn't handle paging that well...